# Arduino Yun not showing up in Windows or Linux [software issue?]

Tags: serial, arduino-yun

I've got my Arduino Yun (less than a year old) connected to my computer via a USB cable. The device seems to be on (that is, the lights are all on). However, the Arduino is not showing up in either the /dev/ttyACMx (linux) or COMx on my Windows boot. Does anyone have any suggestions for why this could be? I've tried to reset the Yun to factory settings by holding the WRT RST button for 30+ seconds, but that still didn't fix anything.

I'm afraid that I'm now looking at a bricked Yun; if this is the case, what could / should I do?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have the 1.6.0 version running. I'm indeed using a microUSB cable to connect to the arduino via USB. If I'm connected to the Arduino-90xxxxxxx wifi network, I can still push sketches to the arduino. However, I'm unable to see the arduino over serial, both in the IDE / terminal. The only port I see in the IDE is 192.168.240.1

EDIT2: I was able to see my Arduino Yun in the IDE again after flashing the blink sketch via wifi and resetting the 32u4. This makes me think that it's a software issue due to the sketch I'm pushing. **Is there something that I could be calling which would make the Arduino unable to connect via serial?**

Comment: Can confirm that connecting to the YUN via WiFi and flashing some simple program like the blink sketch to it will fix the issue. Would suggest moving your EDIT2 to a self answer so it's obvious there is a solution found.